# Extract single Object from Object list in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-6.1.x

Ok, the headline is bit confusing, but i didnt know, how to describe my problem in a short version. Here we go: I get a list of image-urls from the resources of one page, it works like this:

```
lib.slider = FILES
lib.slider {
  references {
     data = levelmedia:-1, slide
  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    data = file:current:publicUrl
    wrap = {image :'|'}
  }

}
```

Now i want to make an image-container from each of the images. I'm not very good in typoscript so i have no idea, how to do that. I had the idea of making an array out of it and using the f:for-Viewhelper but I dont know how to get an array from this or how to access the images from html.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your own findings, you can modify the `renderObj` to be an `IMAGE` cObject, like the following - that way you can define dimensions of your images as well.

```
lib.slider = FILES
lib.slider {
  ...
  renderObj = IMAGE
  renderObj {
    file {
      import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
      maxW = 150
    }
  }
}
```

See the [FILES documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/Files/) and [IMAGE documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/Image/) for further examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution myself, ich just changed the wrapper to `<img src="|" />` and got what i wanted